# How can I check which startup arguments was R started with

Tags: r, environment-variables, startup

Say I launch R with `R --arg1=1 --arg2=2` can I find those arguments from within the R session itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is `commandArgs()` which

> *`Provides access to a copy of the command line arguments supplied when this R session was invoked.`*

So to assign your command line arguments to an object inside R you can do..

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
```

The `TRUE` is optional but will only return the args you passed on the command line immeidately after the `--args` option. `FALSE` returns a whole bunch of other info too.

---

#### On the command line

```
$ R CMD BATCH '--args a=1 b=2' myscript.R myscript.Rout
```

#### Inside R

```
commandArgs(TRUE)
#a b 
#1 2
```

Comment: Actually does this really work ? `R --vanilla` and within R `commandArgs(TRUE)` gives nothing... I am nor speaking about a Rscript but plain R !

Comment: @statquant re-read the answer. Now you are asking for `commandArgs(FALSE)` or simply `commandArgs()`. When `TRUE` it gives *only* the arguments supplied in `--args`, nothing else.